# Can we connect two overload relays in parallel for the same motor?

Tags: current, motor, protection

The motor peak starting current of 17.5 amps is too high. We have two overloads with range of 4 to 10 amps. If we install them in parallel, what are the consequences?

Comment: If English is not your first language then please add this into your user profile. "Teak" is a type of tree.

Comment: Several questions - why is the starting current higher than the overload range? have you changed the motor? have you changed the operating conditions - heavier load ? Whatever the cause, fitting two overload devices in parallel is NOT a good idea.

Comment: I have edited the question to you appear to be asking. Please re-edit if my assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: What you propose might sometimes work but would almost always not be electrical wiring code compliant.  It may also work so unreliably that you will wish that you had selected the correct thermal (delay, slow acting) overload relay that is better suited for your motor load.

Answer (score 1):

Two overload relays in parallel may not share current equally. The trip current will not be reliably known. The overload should be selected and/or adjusted to match the motor's rated continuous current otherwise it will not protect the motor in case of continuous overload. If "range 4 to 10" means the overload is adjustable to trip in that range, it should be fine for peak starting current of 17.5 amps unless that current is sustained too long. If the motor takes a long time to start, a slower time-constant overload could be used otherwise, the motor power rating is not high enough to reliably start the load.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that if two over-current relays are used and do trip out that the last one to trip will be switching the full current. The contacts may weld.

Answer (score 0):

Over load relays protect the motor based on the motor's rated Full ***LOAD*** Current, not the starting current. All OL relays trip based on an I^2t curve, so the higher the current, the faster it trips. This curve is designed to roughly approximate the thermal damage curve of a standard motor designs. there are different 'classes" of curve based on the maximum time values the motor can withstand; 10, 20 or 30 seconds at Locked Rotor Current, defined as 600% of FLC.

Even the fastest trip curve, referred to as Class 10, will trip in 10 seconds (or less) at 600% of the setting. So if your motor is rated for 10A FLC and you set the OL relay for that, at 17.5A you are at only 175% current and a basic I^2t curve would have the relay trip in roughly 8 seconds. If your 10A motor takes longer than 8 seconds to accelerate the load, you probably have too small of a motor. This was just an example, you did not provide the actual motor FLC you are dealing with here.